# Intersection of two Jordan-measurable sets.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

Let $A\subset \mathbf{R}^{n}$ be a closed rectangle. Define $L$={$C\subset A: C$ is Jordan-measurable}. Prove that if $B,C\in L$ then $B\cup C$, $B\cap C\in L$. Note: my definition of Jordan-measurable set is that C is Jordan-measurable if bd(C) has measure zero, where bd(C) is the boundary of C.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Fernando, please show your efforts about the question.

Comment: Well, $bd(B\cup C)\subset bd(B)\cup bd(C)$ but $bd(B)$ and $bd(C)$ have measure zero so $bd(B)\cup bd(C)$ also have measure zero, this implies that $bd(B\cup C)$ have measure zero too. What do you think of my proof?

Comment: It's ok for your definition of Jordan-mesurable.

Comment: Since A is closed ,the boundary of any subset of A,relative to $R^n$ equals its boundary in the subspace A. So, for the case $B\cap C$ , consider that $bd (B)=bd (A\backslash B)$ and $bd (C)=bd (A\backslash C)$ and apply the "union" case to the complements of $B,C$.